# Solve transcendental equation / maximum likelihood estimation

Tags: real-analysis, statistics

Consider $(X_1,\dots X_n)$ with $$\mathbb P[X=k]=\begin{cases}p_0,&k=0\\\frac{(1-p_0)\lambda^k}{k!(e^\lambda)-1},&k\geq1\end{cases}$$

I want to determine the maximum likelihood estimator of $\lambda$

I arrive at $$\frac{\partial}{\partial \lambda}\log L((p_0,\lambda))=\sum_{i=1}^{n}1_{\{X_i\geq 1\}}(X_i)\big(\frac{X_i}{\lambda}-\frac{e^\lambda}{e^\lambda-1}\big)\stackrel{!}{=}0$$

Which is equivalent to
$$\frac{1}{\lambda}\frac{e^\lambda-1}{e^\lambda}=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}1_{\{X_i\geq 1\}}(X_i)}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}1_{\{X_i\geq 1\}}(X_i)X_i}$$

How do I solve this equation? When can it be solved? (If I didn't make any mistakes this is a transcendental equation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The zero-modified Poisson PMF should be $$\Pr[X = k] = \begin{cases} p_0, & k = 0 \\ \frac{(1-p_0) \lambda^k}{k! \color{red}{(e^\lambda - 1)}}, & k \ge 1. \end{cases}$$

For convenience, denote $$w = \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb 1(X_i = 0),$$ the number of observations in the sample that equal $0$, and $$s = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$$ be the sample total.  It is worth noting that the sample total also happens to equal the total of nonzero observations, since zero-valued observations do not contribute to the sum in either case.  Then likelihood is $$\mathcal L(\lambda, p_0 \mid \boldsymbol x) \propto p_0^w (1-p_0)^{n-w} \frac{\lambda^s}{(e^\lambda - 1)^{n-w}.}$$  Moreover, because $\mathcal L(\lambda, p_0 \mid \boldsymbol x) = g(p_0 \mid \boldsymbol x) h(\lambda \mid \boldsymbol x)$ for suitable functions $g, h$, the joint MLE equals the marginal MLEs.  So we may ignore $p_0$ to search for the MLE of $\lambda$:  the marginal log-likelihood with respect to $\lambda$ is
$$\ell(\lambda \mid \boldsymbol x) \propto s \log \lambda - (n-w) \log(e^\lambda - 1).$$  Its critical points satisfy $$0 = \frac{s}{\lambda} - \frac{(n-w) e^\lambda}{e^\lambda - 1}$$ or equivalently $$\frac{1-e^{-\lambda}}{\lambda} = \frac{n-w}{s}  = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb 1(X_i \ge 1)}{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i}.$$  This agrees with your computation.  Its reciprocal can be interpreted as $$\frac{\lambda}{1-e^{-\lambda}} = \bar X^+,$$ where $\bar X^+$ is the sample mean of the nonzero observations only, and in light of the discussion so far, makes perfect intuitive sense:  since $p_0$ and $\lambda$ are in a sense independently estimable from the likelihood, the information contained in the zero observations is informative only of $p_0$, and the information contained in the nonzero observations is informative only of $\lambda$.  Unfortunately, this equation has no elementary closed-form solution.  We can employ Newton's method to numerically search for the MLE; specifically, $$\lambda_{m+1} = \frac{\lambda_m^2 - 2\bar X^+ (1 - \cosh \lambda_m)}{1 + \lambda_m - e^{\lambda_m}}, \quad \lambda_0 = \bar X^+,$$ should have good convergence characteristics.  For instance, $\bar X^+ = 3$ rapidly converges to the MLE estimate $$\hat \lambda = \lim_{m \to \infty} \lambda_m \approx 2.82144.$$

Comment: How can I reason that the solution to the equation $\lambda/(1-e^{-\lambda})=\bar X^+$ is uniqe? Does it follow from the mean value theorem?

Answer (score 0):

your distribution function is well known, it is a *"Zero modified Poisson distribution"* that is a generalization of the *"Zero Truncated Poisson distribution"*.

For the *"Zero Truncated Poisson distribution"*, there is no a closed form for $\hat{\lambda}_{MLE}$, which is the solution of the following equation

$$\overline{X}_n=\frac{\lambda}{1-e^{-\lambda}}$$

Estimators of $\lambda$ for the zero truncated Poisson distribution are studied in

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Starting from @heropup's answer, there is only one explicit solution of the equation
$$\frac{\lambda}{1-e^{-\lambda}}=k$$
It is given by
$$\lambda=k+W\left(-e^{-k} k\right)$$ where $W(.)$ is the principal branch of [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

To evaluate it, since the argument is small, use the expansion for small $x$ as given in the linked page.

Otherwise, you can have good *estimates* using high order iterative methods. I give you a quite good one
$$\lambda\sim\frac{2 \left(2 k^6-26 k^5+72 k^4+562 k^3-313 k^2-285 k-12\right)}{4 k^5-62   k^4+264 k^3+590 k^2+146 k+3}$$
For $k=3$, it gives $\lambda\sim 2.82297$